# Bootstrap 3: Show the error message with fixed Grid Layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to use `help-block` class to show required field error message just below the field. 
Here how it looks originally without error: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/HgAVP/1/)

I have got issue with grid layout:

> Thanks for telling how put help text after the badge. But my issue keeping the grid intact.

**Issue :**
How can I keep grid layout intact? After adding the error message thats how it looks.

> Should I increase the `row` height?

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting the help-block in between the input and the badge, you can do this instead:

```
$(this).closest('div').append("<p class='help-block'>Example block-level help text here.</p>");
```

Also I suggest you use proper markup for a horizontal form (instead of multiple `.form-inline`), read [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for more info

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I'm not sure what you're asking for, and could you please post a working fiddle that reproduces the problem? your current fiddle doesn't have the email as required plus is missing the jquery library, maybe add the changes you have made too

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline">
    <label class="pocLabel">EMail</label>
    <input type="text" name="MiddleName" class="form-control email">
    <span class="badge">P</span>
</div>
```

In your fiddle you are adding the help text with this bit of code:

```
$(this).after("<p class='help-block'>Example block-level help text here.</p>");
```

Where $(this) is the input element.  `.after()`  will put the `<p>` between the `<input>` and `<span>` and since the `<p>` is a block element it will put a break between.

You could try something like this:

```
$(this).next().after('<span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>');
```